# How to use proxy at LinqToTwitter

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, linq-to-twitter

I want to use proxy when using LinqToTwitter. I downloaded source code but there is no proxy feature at HttpWebRequest object. I don't understand how is this happening.

Here what i mean

[image]

This is inside TwitterExecute.cs.

I want to modify it in a way that i can set different proxy for each thread.

So my question is how to modify to use proxy server when posting a status tweet etc?

Comment: Have you included the following namespace ->
using System.Net;

Comment: @anees Yes definitely.

Answer (score 1):

The proxy you're looking at supports Silverlight. I recently added a Proxy property to ITwitterAuthorizer:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#LinqToTwitterAg/OAuth/ITwitterAuthorizer.cs

This is type WebProxy, which you can assign whenever you instantiate an authorizer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy(v=vs.110).aspx

**Updated Sample Code:**

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer 
{ 
    Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials 
    { 
        ConsumerKey = srtwitterConsumerKey, 
        ConsumerSecret = srtwitterConsumerSecret, 
        OAuthToken = srtwitterOAuthToken, 
        AccessToken = srtwitterAccessToken 
    } 
};

auth.Proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/",true);

var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(auth);
```

I've also seen where people have used configuration files to specify their proxy since LINQ to Twitter v2.1.x uses HttpWebRequest:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex(v=vs.110).aspx

LINQ to Twitter v3.0 supports IWebProxy on IAuthorizer:

https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#LinqToTwitterPcl/Security/IAuthorizer.cs

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i couldn't understand. I am using C# 4.5. Using as below way. Can you tell me how to use ? 

var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
             {
                 Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
                 {
                     ConsumerKey = srtwitterConsumerKey,
                     ConsumerSecret = srtwitterConsumerSecret,
                     OAuthToken = srtwitterOAuthToken,
                     AccessToken = srtwitterAccessToken
                 }
             };
            var twitterContext = new TwitterContext(auth);

Comment: If you're using SingleUserAuthorizer, get all 4 of your tokens from your Twitter application account. I updated the code in my answer to show this.

Comment: @JoeMayo Does the proxy work as intended.  I saw on Github that proxy was an open issue but not sure if it's the same or not.  It gives me a 407 proxy authentication error and when I add in this line: myproxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("donmain\\username","password);  I get a {"Invalid or expired token. - Please visit the LINQ to Twitter FAQ (at the HelpLink) for help on resolving this error."}

Comment: The proxy issue on GitHub is for L2T v4.0. If you're using a non-WinRT v3.x then it should be there. Like the message says, look at the FAQ to see if there are any tips to help you. Maybe you can find a way to debug without the proxy, to eliminate it as a potential problem. Then, if you have auth working, then use the proxy again. The proxy is only plugging into the HttpClient proxy, but surfaced through TwitterContext for convenience. Getting OAuth working first is always the hardest part and something in-between, like a proxy, can make it a little more confusing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the folder called `LinqToTwitterProxy` inside the LinQToTwitter Package.  It contains workaround to bypass the proxy.
I hope that will helpout to resolve your issue.